# Improving Bitmap to Line Conversion for a CoreXY Writing Device

Tags: android, kotlin, arduino, bitmap

I am currently working on a CoreXY-based writing device that uses a pen to write text on paper, controlled by an Arduino. To convert text into writing instructions, I need to process a bitmap image and connect the lines in a way that mimics human handwriting. Unfortunately, I found that the Arduino is not powerful enough for this task, so I'm planning to develop an Android app using Kotlin to perform the bitmap processing and then send the resulting information to the Arduino via Bluetooth Serial.

The main challenge lies in converting the bitmap image to a set of connected lines. I have already tried various approaches, including looping through the pixels to connect them in X and Y directions, but the results were less than satisfactory, with strange artifacts and stretching.

Currently, I am using the Douglas Peucker algorithm, but I don't fully understand it, and it's causing issues with stretching and artifacts as well.

The image I am using for testing can be found here:
[image: Test Image]

Current Output:
[image: Current Output]

I am seeking help from more experienced developers to find a better solution for converting the bitmap into connected lines in a way that produces natural-looking handwriting. Any suggestions, improvements, or alternative algorithms that can achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Additionally, here is the relevant Kotlin code I am currently using for the bitmap-to-line conversion:

ImageToPixels.kt:

```kotlin
package com.fyreblitz.fyredrawer.converters

// import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.graphics.get
import kotlin.math.abs
import kotlin.math.pow
import kotlin.math.sqrt

data class Pixel(val x: Int, val y: Int)
data class Line(var pointOne: Pixel, var pointTwo: Pixel, var color: Int = Color.RED)

class ImageToPixels(private val src: Bitmap, private val contrastValue: Double) {
    private val HEIGHT = 1123
    private val WIDTH = 729

    private val _pixels = mutableListOf<Pixel>()
    private val _lines = mutableListOf<Line>()

    fun convert(): Pair<Bitmap, MutableList<Line>> {
        val scaledSrc: Bitmap = resizeBitmap(src)

        val width: Int = scaledSrc.width
        val height: Int = scaledSrc.height
        var paddingRight = 0
        var paddingLeft = 0

        if (height < HEIGHT) paddingLeft = HEIGHT - height
        if (width < WIDTH) paddingRight = WIDTH - width

        val bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, scaledSrc.config)
        val contrast: Double = ((100 + contrastValue) / 100).pow(2.0)

        var lastYPixel           = Pixel(-5, -5)
        var firstConnectedYPixel = Pixel(-5, -5)
        var lastConnectedYPixel  = Pixel(-5, -5)
        for (x in 0 until width) {
            for (y in 0 until height) {
                val pixel = scaledSrc[x, y]
                val newPixel = applyContrastOnPixel(pixel, contrast)
                bmOut.setPixel(x, y, newPixel)

                val hsv = FloatArray(3)
                Color.colorToHSV(newPixel, hsv)

                if (hsv[2] > 0.6f) {
                    bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(255, 255, 255))
                    continue
                }
                bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(0, 0, 0))

                // Compute y Line relations
                /* if (y - lastYPixel.y == 1 && lastYPixel.x == x) {
                    if (firstConnectedYPixel.y < 0) firstConnectedYPixel = lastYPixel
                    lastConnectedYPixel  = Pixel(x, y)
                } else if (lastConnectedYPixel.y - firstConnectedYPixel.y > 1 && lastYPixel.x == x) {
                    _lines.add(Line(firstConnectedYPixel, lastConnectedYPixel))
                    lastConnectedYPixel  = Pixel(-5, -5)
                    firstConnectedYPixel = Pixel(-5, -5)
                }*/

                // lastYPixel = Pixel(x, y)
                _pixels.add(Pixel(x, y))
            }
        }

        _lines.addAll(connectPoints(_pixels, 1.0))
        val linesBitmap = renderLinesToBitmap(bmOut, _lines)
        return Pair(linesBitmap, _lines)
    }

    private fun renderLinesToBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, lines: List<Line>): Bitmap {
        val result = bitmap.copy(bitmap.config, true)
        val canvas = Canvas(result)
        val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
        paint.color = Color.RED
        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        paint.strokeWidth = 1f

        for (line in lines) {
            paint.color = line.color
            canvas.drawLine(
                line.pointOne.x.toFloat(),
                line.pointOne.y.toFloat(),
                line.pointTwo.x.toFloat(),
                line.pointTwo.y.toFloat(),
                paint
            )
        }

        return result
    }

    private fun connectPoints(points: List<Pixel>, epsilon: Double): List<Line> {
        val connectedLines = mutableListOf<Line>()
        val simplifiedPoints = douglasPeucker(points, epsilon)

        for (i in 0 until simplifiedPoints.size - 1) {
            val line = Line(simplifiedPoints[i], simplifiedPoints[i + 1])
            connectedLines.add(line)
        }

        return connectedLines
    }

    private fun douglasPeucker(points: List<Pixel>, epsilon: Double): List<Pixel> {
        if (points.size < 3) {
            return points
        }

        val resultList = mutableListOf<Pixel>()
        val stack = mutableListOf<Pair<Int, Int>>()
        stack.add(Pair(0, points.size - 1))

        while (stack.isNotEmpty()) {
            val (startIndex, endIndex) = stack.removeAt(stack.size - 1)
            val line = Line(points[startIndex], points[endIndex])

            var maxDistance = 0.0
            var maxDistanceIndex = -1

            for (i in startIndex + 1 until endIndex) {
                val distance = calculatePerpendicularDistance(points[i], line.pointOne, line.pointTwo)
                if (distance > maxDistance) {
                    maxDistance = distance
                    maxDistanceIndex = i
                }
            }

            if (maxDistance > epsilon) {
                stack.add(Pair(startIndex, maxDistanceIndex))
                stack.add(Pair(maxDistanceIndex, endIndex))
            } else {
                resultList.add(points[startIndex])
            }
        }

        resultList.add(points.last())
        return resultList
    }

    private fun findMaxDistanceIndex(points: List<Pixel>, startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int): Int {
        var maxDistance = 0.0
        var maxDistanceIndex = -1

        val start = points[startIndex]
        val end = points[endIndex]

        for (i in startIndex + 1 until endIndex) {
            val distance = calculatePerpendicularDistance(points[i], start, end)
            if (distance > maxDistance) {
                maxDistance = distance
                maxDistanceIndex = i
            }
        }

        return maxDistanceIndex
    }

    private fun calculatePerpendicularDistance(point: Pixel, lineStart: Pixel, lineEnd: Pixel): Double {
        val xDiff = lineEnd.x - lineStart.x
        val yDiff = lineEnd.y - lineStart.y

        val numerator = abs((yDiff * point.x) - (xDiff * point.y) + (lineEnd.x * lineStart.y) - (lineEnd.y * lineStart.x))
        val denominator = sqrt(((yDiff * yDiff) + (xDiff * xDiff)).toDouble())

        return numerator / denominator
    }

    // Checks for connected pixels in any direction.
    /*private fun computeConnected() {
        // xLinesSorted1.sortBy { it.pointOne.x }
        // xLinesSorted2.sortBy { it.pointTwo.x }
        val pixelsSortedByY = _pixels
        pixelsSortedByY.sortBy { it.y }
        val pixelsSortedByX = _pixels
        pixelsSortedByX.sortBy { it.x }

        var lastPixel: Pixel? = null
        val connectedXPixels    = mutableListOf<Line>()
        val connectedYPixels    = mutableListOf<Line>()
        val softConnectedPixels = mutableListOf<MutableList<Line>>()

        // Connecting the X Pixels
        for (pixel in pixelsSortedByY) {
            val x: Int = pixel.x
            val y: Int = pixel.y

            // Makes sure we don't waste computing power
            if (lastPixel == null) {
                lastPixel = pixel
                continue
            }

            // Log.d("RenderPixels", pixel.toString() + "\n" + lastPixel.toString())
            if (((x - lastPixel.x) <= 1) && (lastPixel.y == y)) {
                // Connect those pixels in the list.
                if (connectedXPixels.size <= 0) {
                    connectedXPixels.add(Line(lastPixel, pixel, Color.RED))
                    continue
                }

                val XPixelConnected    = connectedXPixels.last()
                val XPixelConnectedIdx = connectedXPixels.indexOf(XPixelConnected)
                // Log.d("RenderPixels1",lastPixel.x.toString() + " " + XPixelConnected.pointTwo.x.toString())
                if (
                    XPixelConnected.pointTwo.x < x &&
                    //lastPixel.x - XPixelConnected.pointTwo.x <= 1 &&
                    XPixelConnected.pointOne.y == XPixelConnected.pointTwo.y
                )
                    connectedXPixels[XPixelConnectedIdx].pointTwo = pixel
                else
                    connectedXPixels.add(Line(lastPixel, pixel, Color.RED))
            }

            lastPixel = pixel
        }

        lastPixel = null
        for (pixel in pixelsSortedByX) {
            val x: Int = pixel.x
            val y: Int = pixel.y

            // Makes sure we don't waste computing power
            if (lastPixel == null) {
                lastPixel = pixel
                continue
            }

            // Log.d("RenderPixels", pixel.toString() + "\n" + lastPixel.toString())
            if (((y - lastPixel.y) <= 1) && (lastPixel.x == x)) {
                // Connect those pixels in the list.
                if (connectedYPixels.size <= 0) {
                    connectedYPixels.add(Line(lastPixel, pixel, Color.GREEN))
                    continue
                }

                val YPixelConnected    = connectedYPixels.last()
                val YPixelConnectedIdx = connectedYPixels.indexOf(YPixelConnected)
                // Log.d("RenderPixels1",lastPixel.y.toString() + " " + YPixelConnected.pointTwo.x.toString())
                if (
                    YPixelConnected.pointTwo.y < y &&
                    lastPixel.y - YPixelConnected.pointTwo.y <= 1 &&
                    YPixelConnected.pointOne.x == YPixelConnected.pointTwo.x
                )
                    connectedYPixels[YPixelConnectedIdx].pointTwo = pixel
                else
                    connectedYPixels.add(Line(lastPixel, pixel, Color.GREEN))
            }

            lastPixel = pixel
        }

        // Connecting the Y Pixels
        _lines.addAll(connectedXPixels.filter { it.pointOne.x - it.pointTwo.x < -6 })
        _lines.addAll(connectedYPixels.filter { it.pointOne.y - it.pointTwo.y < -6 })
        Log.d("RenderedPixels", connectedXPixels.toString())
        Log.d("RenderedPixels", connectedYPixels.toString())
    }*/
    private fun applyContrastOnPixel(pixel: Int, contrast: Double): Int {
        val R = Color.red(pixel)
        val G = Color.green(pixel)
        val B = Color.blue(pixel)

        var Rnew = (((R / 255.0 - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0
        Rnew = Rnew.coerceIn(0.0, 255.0)

        var Gnew = (((G / 255.0 - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0
        Gnew = Gnew.coerceIn(0.0, 255.0)

        var Bnew = (((B / 255.0 - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0
        Bnew = Bnew.coerceIn(0.0, 255.0)

        return Color.rgb(Rnew.toInt(), Gnew.toInt(), Bnew.toInt())
    }

    private fun resizeBitmap(image: Bitmap): Bitmap {
        val sourceWidth: Int = image.width
        val sourceHeight: Int = image.height

        val sourceRatio = sourceWidth.toFloat() / sourceHeight.toFloat()
        val targetRatio = WIDTH.toFloat() / HEIGHT.toFloat()

        val targetWidth: Int
        val targetHeight: Int

        if (targetRatio > sourceRatio) {
            targetWidth = (HEIGHT.toFloat() * sourceRatio).toInt()
            targetHeight = HEIGHT
        } else {
            targetWidth = WIDTH
            targetHeight = (WIDTH.toFloat() / sourceRatio).toInt()
        }

        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, targetWidth, targetHeight, true)
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt:

```kotlin
package com.fyreblitz.fyredrawer

import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.fyreblitz.fyredrawer.converters.ImageToPixels


@Suppress("DEPRECATED_IDENTITY_EQUALS")
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        private const val PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1
    }

    private lateinit var simplifiedPreview: ImageView
    private lateinit var filePickerButton: Button
    private lateinit var selectedBitmap: Bitmap

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        simplifiedPreview = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        filePickerButton = findViewById(R.id.button)

        filePickerButton.setOnClickListener {
            openFilePicker()
        }
    }

    private fun openFilePicker() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent)
    }

    private fun simplifyBitmap() {
        val imageToPixels = ImageToPixels(selectedBitmap, 1.0)
        val simplified = imageToPixels.convert()

        val toast = Toast(this)
        toast.setText("Simplified.")
        toast.show()

        simplifiedPreview.setImageBitmap(simplified.first)
    }

    var someActivityResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult> { result ->
            if (result.resultCode === RESULT_OK && result.data != null) {
                // There are no request codes
                val data: Intent? = result.data

                val selectedImageUri: Uri? = data?.data
                val bitmap: Bitmap? = selectedImageUri?.let { uri ->
                    try {
                        val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
                        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                        null
                    }
                }

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    selectedBitmap = bitmap

                    val toast = Toast(this)
                    toast.setText("Simplifying...")
                    toast.show()

                    simplifyBitmap()
                } else {
                    val toast = Toast(this)
                    toast.setText("Confused screaming?!")
                    toast.show()
                }
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: The reason I am rendering it rather than sending it to the device directly was because, well, I don't wanna waste like 10 minutes until it's finished drawing this behemoth every time I try to debug it.